Git: Display a list of branches found using `grep`, and allow selection by entering the branch number
I am running next command to find branch by text pattern and auto checkout it:
 git checkout $(git branch | grep search_text | head -n 1)

However, there are cases where more than one branch matches the specified text.
Is it possible to display a numbered list and allow selecting a branch by entering the corresponding number for checkout?

You'd have to write a bit of code for that. The above looks like POSIX or Bash, do you want to use that language?

Yes, I am using bash in my project. I know that I will need to create somehow include it as a part of git

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43003385/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+switch+branch+number
